# How to get Box access token from a webpage html or javascript?

Tags: javascript, oauth, box-api, box, boxapiv2

Hi I'm trying to login a user to Box.com from a webpage. I accomplished the first part with a simple HTML form submit:

```
<form action="https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize" type="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" name="response_type" value="code">
    <input type="text" name="client_id" value="[REMOVED]">
    <input type="text" name="state" value="vexhax97td8xf_SomeTemporaryValueForTesting">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This works fine, and I get the authorization code from the query parameters using javascript. I then try the same thing to get the access code (the auth-code is set by javascript on page load):

```
<form action="https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/token" type="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code">
    <input id="auth-code" type="text" name="code" value="">
    <input type="text" name="client_id" value="[REMOVED]">
    <input type="text" name="client_secret" value="[REMOVED]">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But I get an "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing" error. Plus this wouldn't be a good user experience to show the response json anyway. I've tried it without the `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and get the same error.

The Box tutorial does it with curl which obviously isn't an option on a webpage. How do I get the access token without hitting the "Invalid..." error and is there a way to do this via javascript behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

For the authorization-code to access-token exchange, "redirect_uri" parameter is missing. But this is not the real problem.

The exchange is supposed to take place on the server-side and you are doing it on the client-side (browser). Maybe you could do the exchange by AJAX call to correctly handle JSON reply but only if box.com allows CORS (which I doubt).

This way you would also expose your client_id and client_secret on your web page (so why do you hesitate posting it on the stackoverflow?).